# Comparing similar tables in different SQL Server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

While Googling for a way to compare two tables (same schema) that are located in two different databases, I came across the `tablediff.exe` utility which works great for creating a script to make changes in table B so that it matches table A.

However, in my case I need changes to be made to table B **only** if the data in B is older than that of A. Otherwise, the change needs to be applied to table A.

Is there a way to do it using `tablediff.exe`, and if not is there any free command line alternative?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You could try on linked server, so that you could do query between two different server.

Comment: Thanks @JiachengGao that is what I am doing, but the tables are quite large and the servers are connected via WAN which makes the process too slow. Somehow, tablediff is able to make the comparisons very quickly but the problem with it is it cannot decide which record on which table should be updated.

Comment: @Osprey, I'm not quite familiar with this tool, you could set the -sourceserver option of the tablediff utility to the first server and the -destinationserver option to the second server.I found some posts may could solve your problem, would you mind check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722846/use-tablediff-to-compare-all-tables

Comment: @JiachengGao the problem is that tablediff is one directional, that is, it has a source table and a target table. I need the changes to be bidirectional and to depend on which record was updated last.

Answer (score 0):

The Community (free) version of Visual Studio has 'Data Comparison...' for SQL projects.  Right click on the object in SQL Server Object Explorer and specify Source and Target...

Here are some screen shots

Right click (in VS (Dark Mode) SQL Server project) in the SQL Server Object Explorer on the Table to compare.

[image]

Connect to the 2 instances

[image]

Then select the object(s) and voila!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for teh elaborate answer @SteveC . I just tried that and although it has its uses, this seems to have the same problem as Tablediff, that is the changes are one directional. I need the decision on which table gets to copy the record from the other to depend on which data is older. One table might have newer records while at the same time have older ones. In other words, the sync operation might copy records over from both tables in one operation.

Comment: O ok you're specifically interested in data differences.  Paid vendor tools from Quest, Redgate, etc have "data diff" but not VS sadly

Comment: Some of these vendors offer free trials :)  Free like a puppy

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on the conversation from above, but to add to SteveC comments, Visual Studio does have a Data Compare utility.

Tools > SQL Server > New Data Comparison

Comment: Thanks @Terry, but that is what SteveC suggested below and unfortunately it is not what I am looking for since it is unidirectional.